# Strange behavior while scaling treatments over many CPUs

Tags: java, performance, scalability

I am studying performances while scaling java code over many CPUs. For that, I wrote a simple program that runs 50000 fibonacci on one thread, then 2*50000 on two threads, 3*50000 on three threads and so on, until the number of CPU of the target host is reached.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class MultiThreadScalability {

    static final int MAX_THREADS = 4;
    static final int NB_RUN_PER_THREAD = 50000;
    static final int FIBO_VALUE = 25;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MultiThreadScalability multiThreadScalability = new MultiThreadScalability();
        multiThreadScalability.runTest();
    }


    private void runTest() {
        int availableProcs = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        System.out.println(availableProcs + " processors available");

        for (int i = 1 ; i <= availableProcs ; i++) {
            System.out.println("Running scalability test for " + i + " threads");
            long timeInMillisecs = runTestForThreads(i);
            System.out.println("=> " + timeInMillisecs + " milli-seconds");
        }
    }


    private long runTestForThreads(int threadsNumber) {
        final int nbRun = NB_RUN_PER_THREAD * threadsNumber;
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadsNumber);

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for (int i = 0 ; i < nbRun ; i++) {
            Runnable worker = new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    fibo(FIBO_VALUE);
                }
            };

            executor.execute(worker);
        }

        executor.shutdown();

        while (!executor.isTerminated())
        {}

        return (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
    }


    private static long fibo(int n) {
        if (n < 2) {
            return (n);
        }

        return (fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2));
    }

}
```

In the given condtions, I expected that - independent of the number of threads - the execution time remain constant.

I ran it on a power-full machine and I had the following output:

```
48 processors available
Running scalability test for 1 threads
=> 34199 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 2 threads
=> 34141 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 3 threads
=> 34009 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 4 threads
=> 34000 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 5 threads
=> 34034 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 6 threads
=> 34086 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 7 threads
=> 34094 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 8 threads
=> 34673 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 9 threads
=> 35297 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 10 threads
=> 35486 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 11 threads
=> 35913 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 12 threads
=> 36324 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 13 threads
=> 35722 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 14 threads
=> 35750 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 15 threads
=> 35634 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 16 threads
=> 35970 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 17 threads
=> 37914 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 18 threads
=> 36560 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 19 threads
=> 36720 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 20 threads
=> 37028 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 21 threads
=> 37381 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 22 threads
=> 37529 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 23 threads
=> 37632 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 24 threads
=> 39942 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 25 threads
=> 40090 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 26 threads
=> 41238 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 27 threads
=> 42336 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 28 threads
=> 43377 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 29 threads
=> 44394 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 30 threads
=> 46245 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 31 threads
=> 45928 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 32 threads
=> 47490 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 33 threads
=> 47674 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 34 threads
=> 48775 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 35 threads
=> 56456 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 36 threads
=> 50557 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 37 threads
=> 51393 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 38 threads
=> 52971 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 39 threads
=> 53077 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 40 threads
=> 54015 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 41 threads
=> 55924 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 42 threads
=> 55560 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 43 threads
=> 56554 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 44 threads
=> 57073 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 45 threads
=> 65193 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 46 threads
=> 58549 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 47 threads
=> 59302 milli-seconds
Running scalability test for 48 threads
=> 60662 milli-seconds
```

The time remains **almost** the same until 24 threads. The it becomes slower and slower [You can see it on this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NMMr.png)

I asking for help in order to understand why such a "break" happens

Last but not least, the CPU configuration of the host on which I ran the test is the following one:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 46
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E7540  @ 2.00GHz
stepping        : 6
cpu MHz         : 1997.885
cache size      : 18432 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 12
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 6
apicid          : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 11
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat p
se36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc id
a nonstop_tsc pni monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lah
f_lm
bogomips        : 3995.77
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 44 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: [8]
```

Here, I see that the real number of cores is only 6. Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() does not return the number of pysical CPU but the number of "hyper-threads": 48

Do you think it can explain the "break" I observe at 24 threads?

Comment: Is this the entire output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo`? Or is just the output of the first CPU? Since there is a mismatch between this output and the output of `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`.

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me as if your machine has 4 Intel E7540 CPUs, each with 6 cores and 12 threads, giving you a total of 24 cores and 48 threads. So it can execute 24 instructions at the same time.

The 48 threads refers to the hyperthreading feature, which was built to make good use of micro pauses that occur if a thread has to fetch memory to continue. Since your test doesn't access any new memory in the innermost loop, your limited by the 24 cores.

So yes, the number of cores vs. the number of threads explains it.

Comment: What indicates there are 4 CPUs? `cat /proc/cpuinfo` should return 4 entries for 4 physically separate CPUs, I would think. That said, I think it's possible there are 4 CPUs, given the result of Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()

Comment: I assumed that the `/proc/cpuinfo` is incomplete (CPU 0 only). Otherwise, it wouldn't match with the Java output. Let me ask...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this type of adhoc measurement is difficult to do properly. Let's inspect your methods:

1. What version of java are you running? What are the runtime flags given to this JVM?
2. Fibonacci may not be the best CPU test because it loads up the stack -- although you've set it to n=25. In addition, there may be some optimizations your CPU or the JVM performs automatically because you're doing the same thing over and over again. I'd suggest that you modularize this and test a few different load generating functions! Matrix multiplication of randomly seeded matrices would be a reasonable idea or some cryptographic functions such as scrypt hashing on the equivalent of /dev/urandom.
3. Do you see this break on many independent runs in different situations across multiple physical CPUs? 1 test like this isn't sufficient to cause you to question the shape of the curve. Let's try 10 or 20 tests before asking questions (I know you probably have, but I don't see the data).
4. CPUs have a lot of different components! There's the ALU which does simple math, there's several different layers of cache, main controller unit and probably many other unknown little bits to optimize certain operations (hey, Intell has definitely made some improvements since I studied this in detail), all of which may cause the load to scale for different types of operations.
5. The OS is responsible for scheduling threads, and there are many different algorithms that it can use to perform this scheduling function. Any dips or spikes in the graph could be a result of the OS performing this scheduling in different ways (you're testing the behavior of an extremely complex system, it's not unreasonable for there to be such noise).

Answer (score 0):

The Threading task of running FIBO is so CPU intensive that after the first thread, the other threads will hardly have a chance to start.

If you were to create them all and then maybe get them to start all at once, you may see some improvement, but I doubt it.

The good thing about threads is to allow other processing to happen when one particular resource is occupied, but in your example, the only resource that is being taxed is CPU.

Answer (score 0):

With hyper-threading enabled you have 1 physical core running 2  "hardware threads" and they count as a logical processor each.

So your machine have 24 physical cores and 48 logical CPUs (easier to see with command `lscpu`)

Now, the two hardware threads shares the resources of a physical core.

There are resources that are duplicated, shared and partitioned.

It depends on the CPU but usually register state and instruction queues are duplicated, L1 cache and execution units are shared and store/reorder buffers are partitioned.

Usually hyperthreading only give an advantage if the CPU spends good time waiting for (cached) memory.

The OS should try to avoid putting load on a hyper-threaded sibling when there are physcal cores free to use.

Your example is highly CPU intensive, and once the OS starts scheduling two software threads on the same physical CPU core, then the 2 threads start fighting for the same execution units, reducing the scalability.